# How to track and look up coordinates in a 2d array

Tags: ruby

I am working on a problem from adventofcode.com. I need to track the movement on an undetermined grid. I created a move function that uses the case method like this.

```
def move(direction)
  case move
  when ">"
    x += 1
  when "<"
    x -= 1
  when "^"
    y += 1
  when "v"
    y -= 1
  end
end
```

I have to keep track of coordinates visited and I thought of creating a 2d array that keeps track and pushes to the back of it when we visit a new location. What I dont know is how to do keep track of the unique visited locations with an if statement.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you only need to keep track of visited coordinates and their order doesn't matter, then you should use a [Set](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.2.3/libdoc/set/rdoc/Set.html) instead:

```
visited = Set.new

visited << [0,0]
visited << [1,0]
visited << [1,1]
visited << [1,0]

p visited 
# => #<Set: {[0, 0], [1, 0], [1, 1]}>

p visited.include?([1,1])
# => true
```

If for some reason you can't use a Set you can accomplish the same thing with a Hash (this is basically how Set works under the covers):

```
visited = {}

visited[ [0,0] ] = true
visited[ [1,0] ] = true
# Or:
visited.store([0, 0], true)

p visited
# { [0, 0] => true,
#   [1, 0] => true
# }

p visited[ [1,0] ] # => true
p visited[ [2,5] ] # => nil

# Or:
p visited.key?([2,5]) # => false
```

Here's an example of how you could use Set in a Grid class:

```
require 'set'

class Grid
  attr_reader :visited

  def initialize
    @visited = Set.new
  end

  def visit!(x, y)
    visited << [x, y]
  end

  def visited?(x, y)
    visited.include?([x, y])
  end
end

grid = Grid.new

grid.visit!(0, 0)
grid.visit!(1, 0)
grid.visit!(1, 1)
grid.visit!(1, 0)

p grid.visited
# => #<Set: {[0, 0], [1, 0], [1, 1]}>

p grid.visited?(1, 0) # => true
p grid.visited?(3, 3) # => false
```

Comment: If `visit!` is to return `self` regardless of whether the element was added to the set, [Set#add](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.2.3/libdoc/set/rdoc/Set.html#method-i-add) (aka `<<`) is appropriate. [Set#add?](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib2.2.3/libdoc/set/rdoc/Set.html#method-i-add-3F) is also useful, as it to adds the element if it can, but returns `nil` if it can't, avoiding the need to execute `visited?` if that information is desired. It therefore may be worthwhile to have both methods available for adding elements.

Comment: This is really interesting. I've never even heard of sets before. Its probably going to work, I'll test it out tomorrow. I just need the unique locations so will I be able to use .length on it and also are they going to repeat themselves as the locations get revisited?

Comment: Yes, you can use [`Set#size`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.2.3/libdoc/set/rdoc/Set.html#method-i-size) or its alias `length` to get the set's cardinality. I'm not sure what you mean by "repeat themselves," but you can see above what happens when you add the same item to the set twice (the set only keeps one).